# Wanting an explanation of the variables in Iterative PCA algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, python, c++, projection

I've been  trying to implement the CPU GS-PCA algorithm in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1081.pdf) .

The code starts on page 28

I have a program written a script in python which gives the same output as the C++ program in the paper.

My function looks like this

```
[T, P, R, L, U] = IterativePCA(theData, numDimensions, 10000, 1.0e-7)
```

Where `theData` is the big matrix with the data vectors

`numDimensions` is the number of dimensions the PCA algorithm projects onto

I'm using 10000 max iterations

and an error tolerance of 1.0e-7

But I still have a question

What are the matricies `[T, P, R, L, U]` ?

How do I get from them to the new data that has been projected onto the PCA basis?

I can compute this data using

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

PCA(n_components=n_numDimensions).fit_transform(theData)
```

But I want to be able to do it using the iterative method in the paper

Comment: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Parallel-GPU-Implementation-of-Iterative-PCA-Andrecut/d3cfbca16f734e5737ef0d292557222ad7b22076/read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 2.1 in the paper explains that PCA takes a list of vectors

$X = [X^{(0)} | X^{(1)} | ... | X^{(N-1)}]$

and maps it to

$T = [T^{(0)} | T^{(1)} | ... | T^{(N-1)}]$

So I presume $T$ contains the data in the new coordinate system.

It then explains that

$X = T P^T$

So I gather that $P$ contains the principle components.

I'm using the [published source code](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Parallel-GPU-Implementation-of-Iterative-PCA-Andrecut/d3cfbca16f734e5737ef0d292557222ad7b22076/read) now (instead of the preprint version)